# Need specific instruction how to wire UK 3-wire 240v appliance to US 240v wiring and plug

Tags: wiring, 240v

[image: UK Type G 3-wire 240v plug][image: UK Type G 3-wire 240v wall receptacle]

I am looking to install a SIEMENs induction cooktop and downdraft extractor.
They operate on 240v 50/60 hz. I’ve confirmed with Siemens both pieces will run on US 60 hz service.

**I’d like to know so I can inform my local electrician how to wire the appliance into US 240v service and plug.  Both appliances have cables but no plugs.
Should I use a 3-wire NEMA 6-20P plug and receptacle or a 4-wire?**

Can someone explain the crosswalk from appliance's 3-wires 240v to the recommended US 240v 3or4 wire plug?

Siemens Downdraft extractor:

- EAN code : 4242003907122
- Connection rating : 300 W
- Fuse protection : 10 A
- Voltage : 220-240 V Frequency : 50; 60 Hz
- Plug type : GB plug
- Installation type : Built-in

Siemens Induction cooktop

- Electrical connection rating: 7400 W
- Voltage: 220-240 V
- Frequency:    50; 60 Hz
- Approval certificates:AENOR, CE
- Length of electrical supply cord: 110 cm
- Plug type: no plug (electrical connection by electrician)

[image: US NEMA 14 4-wire Plug]
[image: US 3-wire and 4-wire wiring]

**Can someone explain the crosswalk from appliance's 3-wires 240v to the recommended US 240v 3or4 wire plug?**

**Is this the answer?**

Comment: They are clearly not UL approved. If you install them and cause a fire, kiss your insurance goodbye.

Comment: @DoxyLover do you have a source for that?  Wording from an actual policy or some statistics on claims rejected when fires caused by consumer electricals?

Comment: How many wires are there in your cooktop and what color are they?   I just want to verify that the generic "UK plugs" and other diagrams you've included above, are in fact what your cooktop uses, because they don't all use vanilla cords or plugs.

Answer (score 3):

Shipping electrical appliances across oceans is always a mistake.   They sell electrical appliances on this side of the pond, honest.

First - and your electrician may hold your feet to the fire on this - the appliance must be UL-Listed *to USA safety standards* by UL or other Nationally Recognized Testing Lab. BSI and TUV are NRTL's and are capable of certifying European appliances to US standards, *provided they meet* those standards of course.

North America has different standards. *Not least, it does not have RCD protection on cooktops*. So cooktops need to be built to a higher standard.

Either you need to see a NRTL mark on the labeling, with a US endorsement, or you need to get Siemens to supply a letter from UL to that same effect.

If that is available, you can proceed.

---

[image]

There are 3 families of North American plug/socket.

- NEMA 6 family (6-15, 6-20, 6-30, 6-50) are for 240V-only loads which do not need neutral. *This is the one for you*.
- NEMA 14 family (L14-20, 14-30, 14-50) are for appliances which do need neutral, such as American dryers and ovens (neutral for the 120V oven light).   *This range can use a NEMA 14, but it won't connect to neutral if it does.*
- Obsolete NEMA 10 family, which don't have ground and are banned obviously.

You prefer NEMA 6 but can accept NEMA 14. You cannot use NEMA 10.

The circuit breaker size must match up to the load presented by the cooktop, as adjusted by NEC rules on cooktops and ovens, which are weird. The electrician will take care of it.

---

Your connnections are as follows.

UK Earth (green, yellow/green, or bare) to Safety Ground (green, yellow/green, or bare). *Do NOT connect this to neutral (white or gray)*.

In North America, all colors not yet mentioned are hot.

UK Line (brown) to one of the hot wires (might be black).

UK neutral (light blue) to **the other hot wire** (might be red).  Really. Do not connect this to North America neutral, it won't fry anything but will be disappointing.

---

Note that in North America, /2 (twin and earth) cable is black-white-bare.  When it is used for a 240V (no neutral) circuit, both wires are hot and *it is mandatory* to re-identify the white wire to a hot color using tape, paint etc. Red is ideal; black will suffice. There is no need to distinguish the two hot colors *from each other*. Of course many lazy people ignore this requirement and you find hot whites.

For reference: a few others. *Note capacities*.

[image]

Comment: What is the standard or requirement by which appliances imported for personal use in a private home "must be" listed by UL or other lab?

Comment: Don't some European appliances require multiple phases or circuits in a way that may not be easy to implement in the US?   I think actually this one probably needs one 40A circuit but hopefully OP will clarify.  Also if appliance demands a 40A circuit, you'd need a 40A breaker on #8 cable and 50A cord right (because that's what is available) ?

Comment: The personal use requires connecting it to a power source, unless it's an appliance as art object that you don't have to connect to power at all. If you want to **use** it, you are going to be connecting it, and at that point code requirements for NRTL listing kick in. Certainly the cooktop load is a solid 30+Amps which makes it likely that a 40A circuit is required. Might just skip the plug and hardwire it, though.

Comment: My sincere thanks all for the informed answers.
I will ask the import company if they can provide pictures of the wires for both appliances.
@Harper - Reinstate Monica.  I wish this Siemens Glass Downdraft extractor was made by someone else or a close clone.  But it's not; it's unique.  Siemens does not produce home appliances for the non-European market(s).  Alas ....  thank you so very much for the guidance.

Comment: @jay613 Since it's installed.... NEC 110.2, the general requirement to pull permits, and also you promised in exchange for benefits you received. But regardless, "personal use" doesn't have any special status.

Comment: @VAROCKETRY The import company should be responsible for securing entitlements to install the unit, if they mean to sell it here.  See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n07M_m75bKM; some warranties can't be signed away.  I would check with your local AHJ and see if they'll write you a waiver for that unit, using whatever you can get from Siemens to justify it.   I would also get a rider for it with the insurer.  Hey, it's work... but if it was easy, everyone would have a bespoke designed interior.